# Android RecyclerView update item from background listener and move top

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I am working on an instant messaging project. There is a message handler background service which is listening to incoming messages, creates events via greenrobot's eventbus for subscribing Activity, and activity refreshes RecyclerView for updated messages. RecyclerView shows only latest messages of people.

My question is how can i update and move to top a cardview or list item. My current solution is clearing and then adding all messages when a message is received.

You can find implementation of message flow [here](https://gist.github.com/onatm/adfead9e5f3fa3233e39).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RecyclerView.Adapter class stores data in the same way as a BaseAdapter, in an ArrayList. If you want to add an item at a certain position, just insert the object into you data at that specified index. For example you could create a method like this within your ChatHistoryRecyclerViewAdapter.

```
public void addItemAtIndex(int index, ChatHistory chatHistory){
   mChatHistoryList.add(index, chatHistory);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then if you'd like to insert an item at the very top of the list you'd call,

```
mAdapter.addItemAtIndex(0, object);
```

If you need to add multiple items you may consider removing the notifyDataSetChanged() call and only call it after you make all of your updates to the underlying dataset.

Comment: my problem is not about adding a new item, finding an item, updating it and moving to top

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread the issue. Try Collections.swap(mChatHistoryList, mChatHistoryList.indexOf(chatHistory), 0); Then call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: any chance to animate the item while swapping?

Comment: i accepted your answer but could you edit it with the comment above.